# How to generate the EOS keys from Mnemonic/Seed on Expo

Tags: eosio-code, private-key, react

I try to develop the eos crypto wallet app on Expo. But I can't find the solution to generate the eos keys from Mnemonic/seed phrases on Expo.

Once you know the solution, please let me know.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to generate the seed phrase firstly. and hope make the eos keys(private and public keys) from the generated seed phrase.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a string with seed/mnemonic and you need to generate an eos private & public keys from it

```
import * as ecc from 'eosjs-ecc';

function generateKeyPair(seedString){
    const seed = Buffer.from(seedString).toString('hex');
    const privateKey = ecc.seedPrivate(seed);
    const publicKey = ecc.privateToPublic(privateKey);
    return {privateKey, publicKey}
}
```